# String.replaceAll not working outside of Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

**I have the following line of code:**

```
//line is of the format: "Garbage text (desired text)"
String target = line.replaceAll("Garbage text \\((.+)\\)", "$1");
return target; //separated for clarity
```

Output from within `Eclipse Kepler` using `jre1.6`, the above returns to me the desired text. However, when I compile my code into a runnable jar, the above returns the entire string, as if the `replaceAll` was never executed.

When I try

```
line.replaceAll(".+\\((.+)\\)", "$1")
```

I get the same results.

I tried changing my build path to use `jre1.7`, as well, but to no avail.

**My environment:**

```
Windows 7 x64 Professional
Java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: What is `line` and what are your expected results?

Comment: I would clean and rebuild the code just in case some older version be actually executed.

Comment: Try to verify with a Java decomplier like JD GUI (http://jd.benow.ca/) that your jar contains the correct code.

Comment: @JustinJasmann: line could be a variety of things, but keeps this format:,"Telemetry Flow (A)","Telemetry Flow (B)","Telemetry Flow (C)".  The desired for the above, respectively:,"A","B","C"

Comment: @TerryLi: I tried your suggestion, but to no avail. :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It had nothing to do with Eclipse or Java, but all to do with the input file. The jar was running from a different location with a file that had the same name. The two files had slightly different formats, and that is what threw me off.

Thanks for all the help, sorry this was a waste of time.